# What is the simplest possible (as in fewest logic gates) 4-bit by 4-bit binary multiplier?

Tags: logic-gates

I am working on a science fair project, where I am 3d printing a calculator, using water as bits. I have hit a roadblock with my multiplier, however, as my current design uses an absurd amount of resin. I was wondering what the simplest possible (as in the fewest logic gates)design I could use if I want to do a 4-bit by 4-bit multiplier.

Comment: 16 AND gates for the terms and another 8 full adders and 4 half-adders. You may want to go with a Wallace structure given the water as bits. That's combinatorial. You could also structure this as a series ALU. But I've not done that myself. I'd probably go look into the RISC-V SERV implementation to find something there. Might be simpler but would require multiple clock periods. You'll have to disclose a lot more about your project details before I could be of better help, though.

Comment: Are you planing to do a "simple" calculator (just sum, difference and multiplication), or are you aiming for a small micro-controler like calculator? In the second case, you don't need a multiplier at all, as multiplication can be done in several steps by programm (for exemple, the TI 82 calculators (programable calculators for high school) use a micro-controler (z80) which hasn't multiplication in it's instruction set, just bit shifting (ie multiplying or dividing by a power of 2)

Comment: Check out "serial multiplier". Or if you already have a parallel adder, look into multiplication by "shift and add" ... it'll take about 4 clock cycles though.

Comment: @jonk My current design uses 48 logic gates, which is less than the 64 that yours requires. I looked into all of the methods that you mentioned, and they were very useful.

Sandro and user_1818839 I believe that you misunderstood that my calculator is using water as bits. I do not have access to ferrofluids, which would be required to move droplets, so it is going to be very big already, moving about 30cm^2 of water as one bit. An entire microcontroller would likely be taller than my house. I am not looking for efficiency, I am looking for simplicity. I don't really care how fast it is.

Comment: @MichaelStemerman If you can do a 4x4 mutiply with 8 bit output with just 48 2-in logic gates, you need to show me what you are doing. I'd love to learn from you. [Here's what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGKYD.png) for both Wallace and traditional approaches. The [4-bit term looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9FKo.png) and the HA and FA are pretty standard. Now show me yours. Or is your output just 4 bits?